# Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'adminS';

Tags: java, spring

hola que tal porque me marca este error ya tengo todo creado

controller

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminS;

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String showAdmin(Model model, 
            @ModelAttribute("resultado") String resultado) {

        List<Admin> admins = adminS.findAll();

        Admin admin = new Admin();
        model.addAttribute("admin", admin);
        model.addAttribute("resultado", resultado);
        model.addAttribute("admins", admins);

        return "admin";
    }
}
```

service

```
@Service
public class AdminServiceDAOImpl implements AdminService  {

    @Autowired
    private AdminDao adminDao;

    @Override
    public boolean save(Admin admin){
        admin.setFechaCreacion(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));

        return adminDao.save(admin);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Admin> findAll() {
            return adminDao.findAll();
        }


    @Override
    public Admin findById(int id) {
        return adminDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Admin> findByNombre(String nombre) {

        return adminDao.findByNombre(nombre);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Admin admin) {
        return adminDao.update(admin);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(int idAd) {
        return adminDao.delete(idAd);
    }

    @Override
    public int[] saveAll(List<Admin> admins) {
        return adminDao.saveAll(admins);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(Admin admin) {
        if (admin.getIdAd() == 0) {
            // Insert
            admin.setFechaCreacion(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
            return adminDao.save(admin);
        }
        else{
            // Update
            return adminDao.update(admin);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Podrias incluir la definicion de AdminDao?

Comment: import java.util.List;

import com.novellius.pojo.Admin;

public interface AdminDao {
 
 public boolean save(Admin admin);
 public List<Admin> findAll();
 public Admin findById(int id);
 public List<Admin> findByNombre(String nombre);
 public boolean update(Admin admin);
 public boolean delete(int idAd);
 public int[] saveAll(List<Admin> admins);
}

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para incluirla por favor. Asi no hay quien lo lea.